# what does `-t` option of named command stands for?

Tags: named

What does `-t` option of `named` stands for?
It looks like `-d` is already taken by `debug-level`, but where is the `t` come from?
Is it from `chrooT`?

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` option stands for,

> -t directory Chroot to directory after processing the command line arguments, but before reading the configuration file. Warning: This
>   option should be used in conjunction with the -u option, as chrooting
>   a process running as root doesn't enhance security on most systems;
>   the way chroot(2) is defined allows a process with root privileges to
>   escape a chroot jail.

You can refer [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/named) for more details on the command.

Comment: I know what the function of it. I want to know why the alphabet "t" it used for that option.